# Microsoft Store collection REST API, Create Azure AD access tokens returns 404

Tags: azure-active-directory, windows-10-universal

I'm following the Tutorial "Manage product entitlements from a service" [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/view-and-grant-products-from-a-service#step-3),

Am getting stuck on step 3, where calls to request an access token return a 404 error.

**Step1:**  In Azure Portal,

- Created new WebApp, gave it a name & accepted all the defaults.
- Selected the default AD directory and registered the app (used the
  APP URL as the login URL).
- Grabbed the AP ID _APP_ID_ and created app key _APP_SECRET_.
- Updated manifest, replaced identifierURIs as described.

  "identifierUris" : [
      "https://onestore.microsoft.com",
      "https://onestore.microsoft.com/b2b/keys/create/collections",
      "https://onestore.microsoft.com/b2b/keys/create/purchase"
  ],

**Step2:** In MS DevCenter

Added _APP_ID_ to "Services-> Product collections and purchases -> Client ID".

**Step3:** Testing using Postman

I pulled the Azure AD Tenant ID _TENANT_ID_ from the PortalDiagnostics.json.
Using the provided sample, I used postman to post as follows:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/_TENANT_ID_/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8

grant_type=client_credentials
&client_id=_APP_ID_
&client_secret=_APP_SECRET_
&resource=https://onestore.microsoft.com
```

Host and content type are set in the headers, remainder is posted as raw text in the body.

POSTMAN with headers & body
[POSTMAN headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MDen.png)
[POSTMAN body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJi8g.png)

As you can see, the result is a 404 with no body, making this a little tough to trouble shoot.

**Question:**

1. Have I missed something obvious in steps 1 & 2?
2. Should I be able to test this with POSTMAN?

I'd appreciate any pointers; I can't find any other tutorials to cross reference.

Comment: Could you try using Postman's x-www-form-urlencoded tab instead?

Comment: You can also verify the tenant id from the Azure Portal from Azure Active Directory -> Properties -> Directory Id

Comment: Thanks for the sanity check, you hit one issue and and that helped me find the other.  Correct, the POSTMAN body had to use the "x-www-form-urlencoded" tab.  Also, the URL I copied from the tutorial had to remove the "HTTP/1.1" off the end.  Now I'm getting TOKENS!   I'll leave you the honors of posting as the answer. Thx much.

Comment: Hi Chris! Did you manage to get user collections or purchases from your server in the end? Because we walk through all necessary steps, but always end up with empty items. More details here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51968616/1664795.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in this case the problem was a rogue `HTTP/1.1` at the end of the URL + some unencoded content in the form data. Using Postman's x-www-form-urlencoded tab helped for that since it encodes all the fields for you.